# Antlr4: How to exit a grammar rule?

Tags: antlr4

So I"m experimenting with Antlr v4, and I'm poking it with some unusual grammar to get a sense of how it works.  Here's my current test case:

I'd like a grammar that consists of the letters A, B, C, D in that order.  The letters may be repeated. I also group the A's and B's together, and the C's and D's also, to make the grammar more interesting.  So strings like these are acceptable grammars:

AAA

ABCD

ACCCDD

But it's not going well.  I think what is happening is that Antlr needs a better exit rule for my grammar.  It doesn't seem to recognize that after collecting the A's and B's, that the presence of a C means to go to the next rule.  Actually it's sort of working, but I get error messages, and the resulting parse tree seems to have null elements in it, like it inserted an extra element where it issued the error message.

Here's an example error message:

```
line 1:2 extraneous input 'C' expecting {'B', 'A'}
```

which happens for the input 'ABCD'.  So something weird is going on when Antlr sees the C there.  Here's the output of the parse tree:

```
'ABCD': (prog (aOrB (a A) (aOrB (b B) aOrB)) (cOrD (c C) (cOrD (d D) cOrD)) <EOF>)
```

which you can see has an empty aOrB element there at the end of the first set of elements.

Any idea what is going on?  What is Antlr "thinking" here when it issues the error and adds the empty element?  And how might I fix this?

OK, here are the gory details.

My grammar:

```
grammar Abcd;

prog : aOrB cOrD EOF;
aOrB : ( a | b ) aOrB ;
a : 'A'+ ;
b : 'B'+ ;
cOrD : ( c | d ) cOrD ;
c : 'C'+ ;
d : 'D'+ ;
```

My test program in Java:

```
  package antlrtests;

  import antlrtests.grammars.*;
  import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
  import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;

  class AbcdTest {
     private final String[] testVectors = {
        "A", "AABB", "B", "ABCD", "C", "D", };
     public void runTests() {
        for( String test : testVectors )
           simpleTest( test );
     }
     private void simpleTest( String test ) {
        ANTLRInputStream ains = new ANTLRInputStream( test );
        AbcdLexer wpl = new AbcdLexer( ains );
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream( wpl );
        AbcdParser wikiParser = new AbcdParser( tokens );
        ParseTree parseTree = wikiParser.prog();
        System.out.println( "'" + test + "': " + parseTree.toStringTree(
                wikiParser ) );
     }
  }
```

And the output of my test program.  Note the error message are jumbled up with the regular output because they are printed by Antlr on standard error.

```
  run:
  line 1:1 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'
  'A': (prog (aOrB (a A) aOrB) cOrD <EOF>)
  line 1:4 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'
  'AABB': (prog (aOrB (a A A) (aOrB (b B B) aOrB)) cOrD <EOF>)
  'B': (prog (aOrB (b B) aOrB) cOrD <EOF>)
  line 1:1 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'
  line 1:2 extraneous input 'C' expecting {'B', 'A'}
  line 1:4 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'
  'ABCD': (prog (aOrB (a A) (aOrB (b B) aOrB)) (cOrD (c C) (cOrD (d D) cOrD)) <EOF>)
  line 1:0 no viable alternative at input 'C'
  line 1:1 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'
  line 1:0 no viable alternative at input 'D'
  'C': (prog aOrB (cOrD (c C) cOrD) <EOF>)
  line 1:1 no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'
  'D': (prog aOrB (cOrD (d D) cOrD) <EOF>)
  BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this not what you're after?

```
prog : 'A'* 'B'* 'C'* 'D'* EOF;
```

---

The following rule of your grammar matches an infinitely long series of `A` and `B` tokens because the tail recursive `aOrB` reference is not optional. Your grammar will either throw a `StackOverflowException` if the input starts sufficiently many `A` and/or `B` characters, or encounter a syntax error if it does not.

```
aOrB : ( a | b ) aOrB ;
```

If you want to maintain the groupings, you could use this grammar instead. I only made changes to the `aOrB` and `cOrD` rules. Since the `a` rule matches a sequence of `A` tokens, the `aOrB` rule uses `a?` instead of `a*` (only one instance of `a` could ever appear, and the entire series of `A` tokens would be its children).

```
grammar Abcd;

prog : aOrB cOrD EOF;
aOrB : a? b?;
a : 'A'+ ;
b : 'B'+ ;
cOrD : c? d?;
c : 'C'+ ;
d : 'D'+ ;
```

Here is another grammar that matches the same language (but produces a different parse tree) showing other options for the `*`, `+`, and `?` quantifiers. I wouldn't recommend *using* this grammar, but you should look over it very carefully to understand what each choice is doing and understand why it matches exactly the same input as the grammar I gave above.

```
grammar Abcd;

prog : aOrB cOrD? EOF;
aOrB : a* b;
a : 'A' ;
b : 'B'* ;
cOrD : (c d* | d+);
c : 'C'+ ;
d : 'D' ;
```

Comment: Well, part of the idea is to make the grammar do a bit more parsing than what you have above.  This is a simplified test case for more complicated things, so I'd like to avoid these kinds of highly simplified answers like you have there.  In short, no it's not what I'm after.

Comment: @user2338547 I edited by post to include a grammar closer to what you have.

Comment: OK, the expanded answer helps.  It's not quite what I wanted, but I think it does answer the question I asked.  I'll mark this as answered and give it a good long think before the next question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you realize that your aOrB rule doesn't enforce any ordering of a's and b's?  Likewise your cOrD rule.

Comment: Yes, technically, the AB's should be able to repeat ad infinitum before going to the CD's.  But you're right I didn't force the A's and B's to appear in order, which I should have.  I'm still learning! ;)

Comment: No it wouldn't. You are correct about interleaved `A` and `B`, but the `aOrB` rule in the original question can never terminate so the stream can never end and the only symbols it can contain are `A` and `B` (no `C` or `D`).